# HighCharts basic bar chart provide the xAxis categories with Series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the below mentioned [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/uco5anwq/1/)

The categories for the chart are added from this code:

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        }
```

I want to put the code for adding categories for chart inside the function `addseriesToChart`. But I don't know how. The reason I am doing this is becuase I will get the name,id and data for the series as Json string. I am thinking if its possible to some how add the categories also as a part of my Json data.

Comment: Apart of mentioned setCategories, you can set the type xAxis as category and define "name" param per each point. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/puov7e6r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories)

For example

```
var jsonData = {
  id: '123',
  name: 'Total Points',
  categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],      
  data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38]
}

function addseriesToChart(jsonData){
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(jsonData.categories);
    chart.addSeries({
       id: jsonData.id,
       name: jsonData.name,
       data: jsonData.data
    });
}
```